# how to put data into database without using coding, to use in android application

Tags: android

I want to create database and enter data .But i do not want to write code to insert all that data in database in my application.So my question is .is there any way to create database and enter data manually without using code and later use this database in any application(for example android) to retrieve data whenever required to use the data in application.
thank you

Comment: SQLite files are machine-neutral. You can load up data on the PC -- using whatever tool you like, sqlite.exe, a visual editor, etc -- and then attach to that database on Android. (SQLite supports attached databases -- so the extra data can be separated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably install an SQLite editor (if you are using SQLite) on your phone or PC.

- [SQLite editor for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor&hl=en)
- [SQLite Browser for PC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Comment: I was using a Firefox plugin (SQLite Manager) for SQL Lite, it is pretty good for a couple of small ROR projects I did. Probably going to try SQLite Browser,  good to know there are other options.

Comment: by using sqlite browser database can be created but how to attach that database in aplication(or apk). If the application is installed in moblie data will be there or not .I have gone through some tutorial which uses the path to use the data.how can i use the data.thank you

Comment: Take a look here - http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/